# How to update states for every microsecond in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket, currency, stock

I'm using **currency.com's** API to fetch market data and display it on my react-native app. Since the socket response from currency.com is real-time and changes very fast and frequently the **setState() function is called every time the response is triggered.**

This is updating the values but I **couldn't navigate or click or do any other interaction on the app.** The real-time updates are making the setState run continuously and it is **blocking other interactions.**

The interaction is taking place after a very long time.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

[[image: 1]]

Comment: Just update less frequent... ?

Comment: If your asking *how* to make it update less frequent, google debounce.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I couldn't use debounce. I want the values to be updated in real-time. Isn't there a efficient way to update states in real-time in react-native?